# How to display text from text file on button text

Tags: c#

Hello I need your help

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@ ".txt");
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count(); i++) {
  button10.Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
  button11.Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
  button12.Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
  button13.Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
  button14.Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
  button15.Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
  button16.Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
  button17.Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
}
```

it is showing just last line from text file on all button text

EDIT

I was trying to play with array and list but have a new problem now

```
List<Button> button = new List<Button> { button10, button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16, button17 };
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@".txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < button.Count(); i++)
            button[i].Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
```

"Index was outside the bonds of the array" i am getting this error

Comment: Well, you're setting all buttons to the same string and after the loop is done that would be the last line.

Comment: You set every button to have the value `lines[i]`. So obviously they all get the same content. First time you loop, they all get the content of the first line. Second time you loop, they all get the content of the second line...and so on, until the end. But it happens so fast you probably don't notice, and all you can see is the result of setting them all to the value of the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined what behavior you're expecting, so I'm going on a limb here and assuming that you want each button to get a line from the array. I'd start with something like that:

```
// Collection of all buttons.
Button[] buttons = new Button {
    button10,
    button11,
    button12
    // etc
}
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@ ".txt");

// Assinging first line to first button and so on.
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count(); i++) {
    buttons[i].Text = string.Format("{0}", lines[i]);
}
```

Make sure to add boundary checks.

Comment: `string.Format("{0}", lines[i])` can be simplified to `lines[i]`.

Comment: This will create new buttons ? but I need it on exiting one

Comment: Can you understand what my example does? You need the buttons in a collection (the first 4 lines in my example do exactly this). Also see the line after the example - 'make sure to add boundary checks', that's what's causing your problems after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figure it out
I will need to wright more code but it is resolving my problem it is reading line by line

```
string line1 = File.ReadLines(@".txt").First();            
            {
                button10.Text = line1;
            }
            string line2 = File.ReadLines(@".txt").ElementAtOrDefault(1); 
            {
                button11.Text =  line2;
             }
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button15.Text))
            {
                button15.Visible = false;
            }
```